# user_role_revoke_permissions() for administrator

Tags: 8, users

I am using [EU Cookie Compliance](https://www.drupal.org/project/eu_cookie_compliance) module.  During module installation, permission has been set to admin also. I need to revoke that permission which is assigned to Admin as cookie pop-up is coming-up for admin also.
In Permissions, it is `grayed-out`. So I can't able to disable that permission.

When I used below code, it is revoking permission for all other roles but not working for Admin.

```
user_role_revoke_permissions('administrator', [
      'display eu cookie compliance popup',
    ]);
```

Please suggest me a solution how to revoke that permission for admin.

Comment: Admin or `User with uid 1 ` has all permissions, if you revoke permissions for administrator role, it will revoke for all authenticated user.

Comment: yes, I know that, I want give cookie permission only for anonymous user, So need to revoke only " eu cookie compliance popup permission" for admin.

Comment: Have you try to uncheck `Display EU Cookie Compliance banner`  permission for authenticated user?

Comment: Yes, that is working only for authenticated user, not admin.

Comment: For others am posting my answer. This module is providing hook_alter(), with the help of that I have achieved.                                                                      
function hook_eu_cookie_compliance_show_popup_alter(&$show_popup) {
  $current_user = \Drupal::currentUser();
  $roles = $current_user->getRoles();

  if (in_array('administrator', $roles)) {
    $show_popup = FALSE;
  }
}

Comment: You can please post your answer with the proper code, in case someone need it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the snippet code works for [@Saba](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/89572/saba) `original author of the post` in case someone needs it.

```
function YourModuleName_eu_cookie_compliance_show_popup_alter(&$show_popup) {
  $current_user = \Drupal::currentUser();
  $roles = $current_user->getRoles();
  if (in_array('administrator', $roles)) {
    $show_popup = FALSE;
  }
}
```